# Raster and polygon not aligning, even when extent and projargs are same

Tags: r, polygon

I am trying to overlay a spatial polygon (derived from a grid generated by icosa) over a global raster map. I have made sure that the bounding boxes/extents of the objects are equal, and that they are both projected to the same CRS, but the polygon does not align with the extent of the raster correctly. Any ideas? (base image available here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sj6F1.jpg)
[image: misaligned raster and spatial polygon]

```
# required packages
library(icosa)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)

# define projection string
equi <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

# load data and set extent
lad <- raster("Data/Maps/Ladinian_grey.jpg", crs = equi)
extent(lad) = c(-180, 180, -90, 90)

# generate grid and convert to spatial polygon
large_grid <- hexagrid(c(2, 3))
large_grid <- newsp(large_grid)
map_grid <- SpPolygons(large_grid, res = 50)
map_grid <- spTransform(map_grid, equi)

# plot
plot(lad)
plot(map_grid, col = NA, add = TRUE)
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. What is `equi`? Your use of it in `raster(  , crs=equi)` is perhaps wrong. What is `newsp`? Why do you do: `map_grid@bbox[1,1] <- extent(lad)[1]` etc? That is not right; you should never manually change these values.

Comment: I forgot to define 'equi' in my original code (it was used as storage for the equirectangular proj4 argument). I have updated this in the example. 'newsp' is a function from the icosa package. The new code is updated for clarity, although it functions in the same way as in my original code. As for the bbox, I assumed that the bounding box for a spatial polygon and the extent for a raster were analogous and so tried updating the bounds of the former with the latter so their dimensions would match. Doing this didn't fix my problem, but I kept it as per my assumption of matching object dimensions

Comment: You should not change the bbox values because they describe the extent of the object, but do not change it in anyway. So you make a mess when you do that. Instead, you could look at what the values are, e.g.:  `extent(map_grid)`

Comment: Also, it may not matter here, but `"+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"` is _not_ "equirectangular". That would be `proj=equi`.

Comment: I have further edited my code to reflect the following. I took a look and the extents do differ, but there is not a formal slot for defining extent in spatial polygons. Is there any other way to edit its dimensions to that they will align with that of the raster. They are being projected to the same CRS, regardless of what the string is. Ultimately I am converting both to robinson CRS, but the alignment issue persists, so I left robinson projection out for simplicity.

Comment: I think the extents are fine (see my expanded answer)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to see what is going without the data, and the odd things you do changing the extents of objects. The example below suggest that it should work:

```
library(raster)
library(icosa)

r <- raster()
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
large_grid <- hexagrid(c(2, 3))
large_grid <- newsp(large_grid)
map_grid <- SpPolygons(large_grid, res = 50)
plot(r)
lines(map_grid)
```

[image]

The bad alignment you show *can* be caused by resizing the plot after drawing.

It also work fine with your data and (simplified) code:

```
library(icosa)
library(raster)

lad <- raster("f91xQIt.jpg")
extent(lad) = c(-180, 180, -90, 90)
crs(lad) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"

large_grid <- hexagrid(c(2, 3))
large_grid <- newsp(large_grid)
map_grid <- SpPolygons(large_grid, res=50)

# I use image so that it is clearer where all the lines come from
image(lad)
plot(map_grid, col = NA, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

And the extent is as expected

```
map_grid
#class       : SpatialPolygons 
#features    : 362 
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs         : +proj=longlat +a=6371007 +b=6371007
```